# Can I use conditional "or" statements in selecting files to download with wget

Tags: unix, wget

I'm trying to download a bunch of files via ftp with wget. I could do this manually for each of the variables that I am interested in, or I was wondering if I could specify these in an "or" type conditional statement in the filepath name.

For example, I would like to download all files that contain the strings "NRRS412", "NRRS443", "NRRS490", etc. I had planned to do individual calls to wget for each of these, like this:

```
wget -r -A "L3m*NRRS412*.nc" ftp://username:password@ftp.address
```

I cannot simply use `"L3m*NRRS*.nc"`, as there are other "NRRS" strings that I don't want.

Is there a way to download all of my target strings in a single call to wget?

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I figured out the solution, which is to create several possible strings separated by commas:

```
wget -r -A "L3m*NRRS412*.nc, L3m*NRRS43*.nc, L3m*NRRS490*.nc" ftp://username:password@ftp.address
```